# 'Autofac Circular Component Dependency Detected' Error

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I am new to IoC and am using Autofac in my current project.

I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _repo;
    private readonly IMailService _mailService;
    public UserService(IUserRepository repo, IMailService mailService)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _mailService = mailService;
    }
}

public class MailService : IMailService
{
    private readonly IMailRepository _repo;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public MailService(IMailRepository repo, IUserService userService)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _userService = userService;
    }
}
```

Initially, my UserService class didn't require an instance of the MailService class, but now it does, and it's since introducing this into the UserService Constructor that this circular dependency error has arisen, and being a newbie, I'm not sure how to resolve this.

This is how my classes are currently registered in Autofac:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// controllers                      
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UsersController)));

// register other classes
builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<MailRepository>().As<IMailRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>();
builder.RegisterType<MailService>().As<IMailService>();
```

Comment: Can you outline the methods that `MailService` needs from `IUserService` and also what `UserService` needs from `IMailService`? A circular dependency like this usually results in a small refactoring to make explicit some implied third concept.

Comment: Although not always the case, but a circular dependency often indicates a design flaw. If you show more code (what `MailService` and `UserService` are actually doing), we will be able to tell whether this is the case, and how to fix this. Possibly you are missing another abstraction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a UserService needs an IMailService and a MailService needs an IUserService you have a dependency loop. I see a couple of options:

1. Does your UserService need an IMailService right away? Could you pass one in when it needs to send a message?
2. Can either query the resolver on-demand - that is, don't pass IUserService to MailService in the constructor but rather code MailService to resolve IUserService when it needs it?

Comment: Hi n8wrl. My UserService only needs an IMailService from one or two methods within the UserService class, and not immediately when the UserService class is first instantiated. So with Option 1 in mind, what's the best approach for passing in one only when I need to send a message?

Comment: Well, your 'send-a-message' method could take an IMailService parameter, OR (as in option-2) it could call AutoFaq's resolver to get one and then give it up?

Comment: I personally like #2 because I can swap in different IMailService/IUserService implementations (mocks) for testing and, with the proper config, AutoFac will happily serve them up. It also prevents your UserService clients from having to worry about passing in an IMailService.

Comment: How are you resolving on-demand, believe I've run into the same situation and I've tried to implement option 2 but getting "None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter."

Answer (score 5):

[Autofac has documentation on how to handle circular dependencies](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html) that might help here. You can get it to work if you follow the guidance there (which boils down to: make one of the dependencies a property rather than a constructor dependency).