# Resolving cyclical dependency with class that can create instances of itself

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, ioc-container

I'm brand new to Dependency Injection and have been playing around with Ninject trying to make small test applications to get my head around the concepts.  Mark Seemann's [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236) is next on my reading list.

One problem I have run into in my brief testing, is that I do not know how to handle the case where a class can instaniate a new instance of its type.  An example would be a form with a button.  When a user clicks the button, the form creates another form of the same type.

If not using DI, in the above scenario you would just `new` up another form instance in click event handler on the original form.  It is my understanding (and I may be naive in this area) that the preferred method would be to use an abstract factory to create instances and have the class depend on that.

Below is the code I have tried (nothing to do with forms, just plain classes) that does not work due to cyclic dependencies, which I do see why that is occurring.  I just can't think of a good solution that does not require me to `new` something up manually.  I feel like I am missing a key piece.

```
public interface IMainClass
{
    IMainClass CreateNew();
    void Do();
}

public interface IMainClassFactory
{
    IMainClass CreateNew();
}

public class MainClassFactory : IMainClassFactory
{
    private readonly IMainClass _mainClass;

    public MainClassFactory(IMainClass mainClass)
    {
        _mainClass = mainClass;
    }

    public IMainClass CreateNew()
    {
        return _mainClass;
    }
}

public class MainClass : IMainClass
{
    private readonly IMainClassFactory _mainClassFactory;

    public MainClass(IMainClassFactory mainClassFactory)
    {
        _mainClassFactory = mainClassFactory;
    }

    public IMainClass CreateNew()
    {
        return _mainClassFactory.CreateNew();
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do from Main Class");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<IMainClassFactory>().To<MainClassFactory>();
        kernel.Bind<IMainClass>().To<MainClass>();

        var mainClassFactory = kernel.Get<IMainClassFactory>();
        var mainClass = mainClassFactory.CreateNew();

        mainClass.Do();

        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I know this code is incorrect.

- Should IMainClass implement IMainClassFactory?  Does it matter?
- `kernel.Bind<IMainClass>().To<MainClass>();` Doesn't seem right but I don't know what to do
- Is `new`ing up your own objects completely verboten?
- I think I have a pretty good grasp of not using the Service Locator anti-pattern.  I don't want my classes to be aware of any IOC containers.

I'm sure these types of scenarios happen all the time, so I'm looking for the preferred solution in the general case.  If possible, I would like to avoid using any Ninject-specific exotic features in case I want to move to a different implementation.

**Edit 1:**
['Autofac Circular Component Dependency Detected' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638241/autofac-circular-component-dependency-detected-error) 
This question looks similar, but the accepted answer seems like it is advocating a service locator?  Maybe I'm reading it wrong but looks like it violates the Hollywood Principle

Answer (score 0):

From a pure DI perspective, an abstract factory would be the proper way to go, but perhaps you are missing a pattern here:

> When a user clicks the button, the form creates
>   another form of the same type.

Forms should not depend on other forms directly. This hard-wires them together. There should be a centralized point for handling screen navigation and the flow of an application. In other words, what you're missing is an [Application Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html).

Your form should depend on an `IApplicationController` or something similar. This application controller could again depend on an abstract factory that creates new forms.

Comment: Ok, I agree with the application controller for a form, but I don't really care about a form, that was just an example for a real-world use.  I think my code above basically emulates that pattern.  I am asking about the general case using DI.  I am getting stuck on this whole Chicken-And-Egg problem where a class (form or whatever) needs to contain a method that can provide a new instance of the same type.  Passing into a class a factory that creates the class seems logically OK but I am asking how to do it without causing a cyclical dependency.

Comment: The general solution to break cyclic dependencies is property injection. However, this wont work in your case. You need to inject a factory.

Comment: I tried with property injection of a factory and it still gave me the cyclical dependency exception, although there may be a way to do the property injection that doesn't throw it that I just don't know what it is.  If so, that is the answer I would like to see.

Comment: As I said, property injection won't work in your case, since the type depends on a new instance of its self. It doesn't matter whether you use constructor or property injection in that case, because even property injection will cause the dependency graph to be indefinately deep. You'll need to postpone the composition of this object graph, and the way to do this is by using a factory.

Comment: Ok. I will wait and see if someone can provide me an example of how to actually do what you are saying. I'm so far fine with the what and why but would like to see the how.