# Using Autofac's resolver on demand in WebAPI perRequest to handle Circular errors

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I use autofac on basic level to handle dependency injection. My config at the moment is simple:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestDbContext>().As<DbContext, TestDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<TestRepository>().As<ITestRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
```

My problem is kind of related to: ['Autofac Circular Component Dependency Detected' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638241/autofac-circular-component-dependency-detected-error)

I don't want to get Curcular component dependency error so I don't include `IUserRepository` into `ITestRepository` constructor (it's included the other way round).

I wanted to use the second suggestion from the above question's answer. How can I code my `TestRepository` to use `UserRepository` on-demand? I've tried using BeginLifetimeScope with the following attempt:

```
public class TestRepository : ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository()
    {
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        using (var scope = AutofacConfig.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var scopeUserRepo = scope.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the 
instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as 
per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar 
scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the 
DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the 
container itself.
```

Comment: You can also try to use the Func support in Autofac: so in your `public TestRepository(Func<IUserRepository> userRepositoryCreator)` and in your `Test()` method just write: `var scopeUserRepo = userRepositoryCreator();`

Comment: well I kinda figured my design pattern must be wrong if I have those circular errors ;) Though there is an easy solution with using `Lazy<IUserRepository>`, but thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

**You can't just begin a lifetime scope in Web API.** The request lifetime scope is carted around with the request message. By manually creating a request lifetime scope like this, you're not going to get the results you are looking for - *especially* if you have per-request lifetime scope dependencies, because the scope you're creating will not be the same scope as the actual request lifetime. You won't get that lifetime sharing you should be getting.

[There is a detailed FAQ about troubleshooting per-request lifetime scope issues](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) that should help get you on your way. You may also be interested in [the documentation on properly handling circular dependencies in Autofac](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can use ILifetimeScope injected in your constructor:

```
public class TestRepository : ITestRepository
{
    private ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public TestRepository(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
      var scopeUserRepo = _scope.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that but I think it's the worst possible situation. I can use Lazy<T> in constructor and it will work also, but that's also not the best solution.

Comment: I was just rewriting your previous code to avoid autofac errors.  I didn't say it's the best solution.  The right solution should be to refactor your code design, but you don't provide it in your question.