# Configure autofac dependencies for constructor/property service layer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am working to try simplify some of our architecture in an application.

I have 3 projects

- API
- Services
- Repository

Api speaks with the services project and the services speaks with the repository.

Within my service project I need to the ability to consume other services. This will allow me to reduce the amount of repeated code

An example of my code is like this

```
    public class ApplicationService:IApplicationService
    {
    private readonly ILog _log;
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }

    public ApplicationService(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
        if (_log == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("log");
        }
        if (UserService == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("UserService");
        }
    }
   }

public class UserService:IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    public ICustomerService CustomerService { get; set; }

    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

My Startup.cs for the autofac configuration looks like

```
 builder.RegisterType<Services.UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
 builder.RegisterType<Services.ApplicationService>().As<IApplicationService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
 builder.RegisterType<Services.CustomerService>().As<ICustomerService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("MyApp.Services"))
      .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
      .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I did find this older SO post ['Autofac Circular Component Dependency Detected' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638241/autofac-circular-component-dependency-detected-error) which looks pretty much the same as the problem I am having.

Reading the autofac documentation I cant see what I have done wrong [Circular Dependencies](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html)

When the application currently runs and the constructor within the applicationService is called. The UserService property is always null. Why is this the case?

Comment: Why don't you inject `IUserService` via the constructor like you did with `ILog`?

Comment: I tried that but I ran into circular issues. reading the documentation my understanding is you can't use constructor/constructor injection see http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html#constructor-constructor-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Inside ApplicationService constructor execution the UserService will always be null simply because you are not assigning anything to it in the constructor (you are not using constructor injection). So this piece of code will always throw exception:

```
if (UserService == null)
{
     throw new ArgumentNullException("UserService");
}
```

Remove this code and you should be ok. Property injection in in DI containers assigns dependencies to objects properties after object is created with the constructor (there is no other way).

BTW i don't see any circular dependency in the code that you included. You haven't included code for implementations of ICustomerService and IUserRepository so maybe something is there.